# how to convert discrete variable to continus variable for use as NN input?

Tags: math, statistics, neural-network

I have some discrete variables
I want to convert them to continus variables to use as the inputs of a neural network
has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

It results in a large number of input features, but you could use an indicator input (0 or 1) for each *state* of the discrete variable(s).  Technically, you could drop one of these inputs for a given variable, since it is equivalent to all of the others being zero.

Answer (score 0):

Would scaling the discrete values to be between 0 and 1 (or, rather, 0.1 and 0.9 for better numerical behavior) work for your application?